# Possible to have radio buttons not required?

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to use Radio for the possible selection of a field.  I have found that I am required to select one of the values.  Is it possible to use radio buttons for a field and not require the user to select one?  (I don't want to use a null default value as that gives me an odd looking, blank radio button).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

1. Your model field is not required
2. 'Allow null' setting for the radio button is checked

Comment: It is not required.  If I enable 'allow null', then a radio button with a blank value is displayed (which I don't want as it looks odd).

Comment: You can explicitly configure 'Null Item Name' property to make it look better, or use CSS to hide the very first option.

Comment: How would I hide with CSS?  I tried different code including this:
    input[type="radio"][value="[No Selection]"] {
      display: none;
    }

Comment: .app-PageName-RadioGroupWidgetName .app-RadioGroup-Item:first-child {
  display: none;
}